# How to fetch JSON data stored on WAMP to a html page in worklight?

Tags: html, json, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, getjson

I created a JSON file on WAMP:

```
{
"address":[{
"name":"John"
}
]
}
```

And I am unable to retrieve it on HTML page in worklight mobile app.

Comment: "unable" means that you've tried to. How did you try? What did you do?

Comment: You should use HTTP adapters: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf

Comment: What Idan said quite honestly. This looks like a perfect HTTP adapter use case, and your question provides almost 0 information

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON file should be accessible as a URL (`http://localhost/YOUR_WAMP_SERVER/YOU_JASON`).
In Worklight create an HTTP adapter that will point to your server and the procedure will point to your JSON file.
You can use the [HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf)    [Exercise and code sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/WorklightAdaptersProject.zip) from the IBM Worklight Getting Started page as a starting point.